# How to LogIn on IBM iSeries AS/400 using Telnet

Tags: ios, telnet

I am trying to develop a app like terminal emulation of IBM iSeries AS/400. I am using AsyncSocket to connect to server. Connection is fine but how should i LogIn on telnet server using UserName and Password after connection established. Is there any format or command or manner in which i should send the UserName and Password to Server to LogIn.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you'll want to study [RFC 4777 - RFC 4777 - IBM's iSeries Telnet Enhancements](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc4777) pretty carefully.

Note particularly the section on "Standard Telnet Option Negotiation":

```
Telnet server option negotiation [RFC855] typically begins with the
issuance, by the server, of an invitation to engage in terminal type
negotiation with the Telnet client (DO TERMINAL-TYPE) [RFC1091].  The
client and server then enter into a series of sub-negotiations to
determine the level of terminal support that will be used.  After the
terminal type is agreed upon, the client and server will normally
negotiate a required set of additional options (EOR [RFC885], BINARY
[RFC856], SGA [RFC858]) that are required to support "transparent
mode" or full screen 5250/3270 block mode support.  As soon as the
required options have been negotiated, the server will suspend
further negotiations and begin with initializing the actual virtual
device on the iSeries.  A typical exchange might start as follows:

iSeries Telnet server             Enhanced Telnet client
--------------------------        -------------------------
IAC DO TERMINAL-TYPE        -->
                            <--   IAC WILL TERMINAL-TYPE
IAC SB TERMINAL-TYPE SEND
IAC SE                      -->
                                  IAC SB TERMINAL-TYPE IS
                            <--   IBM-5555-C01 IAC SE
IAC DO EOR                  -->
                            <--   IAC WILL EOR
                            <--   IAC DO EOR
IAC WILL EOR                -->


Actual bytes transmitted in the above example are shown in hex below.

iSeries Telnet server             Enhanced Telnet client
--------------------------        -------------------------
FF FD 18                    -->
                            <--   FF FB 18
FF FA 18 01 FF F0           -->
                                  FF FA 18 00 49 42 4D 2D
                                  35 35 35 35 2D 43 30 31
                            <--   FF F0
FF FD 19                    -->
                            <--   FF FB 19
                            <--   FF FD 19
FF FB 19                    -->
```

So you'll actually want to look for those byte code and send the appropriate response.